# Ubuntu VM won’t run tasks in background indefinitely

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I’m having trouble running background tasks in an Ubuntu VM on Google Cloud Compute. When I start the task it runs for some time, but eventually it always stops. Normally this after about 20-30 minutes, but sometimes it lasts an hour.

Things I’ve tried:

- Running the task directly
- Running the task in the primary terminal with nohup
- Running the task in a new terminal using screen
- Running the task in a new terminal using screen and nohup
- Each of the above with sudo

Surely there must be a way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of task? can you get some logs ?  do it crash for a reason ?  Usually, task = systemctl service so that you can manage/monitor them

Comment: It's a python task for a bot that I'm running in the shell. There's no crash, and I'm pretty sure the task itself is reliable because I can run it on my desktop for days with no issues. @wargre

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww That makes sense, but I can't migrate to Server Fault unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely that your task is stopped by the fact that it's running in google cloud platform. Try to log the task states or use strace command to see why it has terminated.
It could be any of the following:

- Network related issues (e.g. your home environmet can connect to resource all the time while the cloud may not[packet loss], or latency issues or network jitter)
- Resource related issues (e.g. your task depletes all the RAM in a while and stops)
- CPU scheduling (e.g. your task requires near real time interactions while the cloud physical CPU may be used between many VMs)

To work around the problem of a crashing/stopping task you could add a crontab entry with someting (dirty) like:

- - - - - pidof "taskname" || nohup /path/to/task

which will execute every minute and check if it can find pid number of your task - if not, it will start it

ad 1) it would be best to diagnose why your task has stopped
ad 2) it would be better to move this to serverfault as @iww suggested